# sort the object of the Array the specific key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have Array of object data which i want to sort objects of the Array by the specific key that is `default`. In the Array of routes. it has some object of the route. I just want to sort according to the `default` key. if the key `default:true` inside object then this object will go to the top and  if `default:true` is found in the more than one object,then always  set top  of first object which found the `default:true` key. Also if we found the key `default:true` in the **subarr:[]** of the object then the it's parent object and this object will go to top. so, please suggest the solution for this.

Input Data:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": 'Dashboard',
    "subrr": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": 'Test'
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": 'Card',
      "default": true,
      "subrr": [
        {
          "id": 4,
          "title": 'notification'
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "title": 'User',
      "subrr": [
        {
          "id": 6,
          "title": 'sample'
        },
        {
          "id": 7,
          "title": 'chart',
          "default": true
        }
      ]
    },
  ];
```

/**************/

Output Data:

```
[
{
      "id": 5,
      "title": 'User',
      "subrr": [
      ,
        {
          "id": 7,
          "title": 'chart',
          "default": true
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "title": 'sample'
        }
      ]
    },
    ,
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": 'Card',
      "default": true,
      "subrr": [
        {
          "id": 4,
          "title": 'notification'
        }
      ],
    },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": 'Dashboard',
    "subrr": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": 'Test'
      ]
    }
  ];
```

Comment: Why would you sort? You only seem to be interested in finding the first object with `default` set to `true`.

Comment: What have you already tried? Can you share a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It would be nice to also include an example expected output result from some sample input data.

Comment: I don't think your output matches a sorting where elements with a `default` property of true or an element within it's `subarr` property having a `default` property of true. Element object with `id` 2 seems like it should be sorted before `id` 1 since it has a `default: true` property.

Comment: In fact, based on how I interpret how you want the data to be sorted I have it ordered (by `id) [2, 3, 1].

Comment: @DrewReese I just want to sort my data object by the default key, either it's true in parent object OR in subarr object

Comment: So you want to first sort by `subarr` having a property `default: true`, then sort by `default: true` in the root?

Answer (score 0):

How I interpreted your sorting requirements:

1. Sort by `element.subarr[i].default` property
2. Sort by `element.default` property.

Create comparator functions for each condition you want to sort by.

```
const byDefault = (a, b) => (a.default === b.default ? 0 : a.default ? -1 : 1);

const bySubArrDefault = (a, b) => {
  const resA = a.subarr.some((el) => el.default);
  const resB = b.subarr.some((el) => el.default);

  if (resA === resB) return 0;
  return resA && !resB ? -1 : 1;
};
```

Now to sort by multiple conditions you will essentially be sorting and grouping, each group being sorted, each sub-group then sorted. The grouping/sorting is achieved by combining all the comparator functions with a logical OR (`||`). This logic tries to find and return the first non-zero comparator function result.

```
data.sort((a, b) => bySubArrDefault(a, b) || byDefault(a, b))
```

This sorts all data elements by the sub array element `default` properties, and then within that group sorts by the root `default` property.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Dashboard",
    subarr: [
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "Test"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Card",
    default: true,
    subarr: [
      {
        id: 4,
        title: "notification"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: "User",
    subarr: [
      {
        id: 6,
        title: "sample"
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        title: "chart",
        default: true
      }
    ]
  }
];

const byDefault = (a, b) => (a.default === b.default ? 0 : a.default ? -1 : 1);

const bySubArrDefault = (a, b) => {
  const resA = a.subarr.some((el) => el.default);
  const resB = b.subarr.some((el) => el.default);

  if (resA === resB) return 0;
  return resA && !resB ? -1 : 1;
};

const sorted = data
  .slice(0)
  .sort((a, b) => bySubArrDefault(a, b) || byDefault(a, b));

console.log(sorted);
```